# Hex to long double c++

Tags: c++, double, type-conversion, long-integer, hex

is anybody know how to convert long double to hex and reverse from hex to long double in c++. I have done some conversion from HEXstring to double using istringstream to long long and cast it to double, but can't figure how to convert long double, and how to test something like that.

Comment: Do you really mean decimal rather than double?

Comment: Are you asking how to print a number in hex and in decimal?

Comment: Do you mean like C99 hex floating point representation, or just the hexadecimal output of the binary data?

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure you want to do this, you max use a union to "cheat the type system". This is raw memory access, obviously, and comes with a large number of caveats. Not the least of which is that it only "usually" works, but is not guaranteed by the language spec.

Code to output the raw bytes of the long double is below. Code to re-assemble a long double from a hex string should not be too hard to provide yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
  long double ld;
  char bytes[sizeof(long double)];
} converter; 

int main() {
  converter c;
  c.ld = 3.49;
  printf("0x");
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(long double); ++i) {
    printf("%x", c.bytes[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR. It might print the bytes, it might not. 
You're accessing an object of which the lifetime has not yet begun. 
Also `char` might be signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting. Here is my solution, anyway.
It should work on any platform where `long double` is a type.

> Except for bit fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, each consisting of CHAR_BIT bits, and can be copied with memcpy into an object of type unsigned char[n], where n is the size of the object. The contents of the resulting array are known as object representation.

See: [C Objects Strict Aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing)

```
// C11
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <string.h> // memcpy, size_t, NULL
#include <assert.h> // assert macro

int main(void) {
  const long double src = 3.1415926L;
  unsigned char dest[sizeof src] = { 0 };
  assert (memcpy(dest, &src, sizeof src) != NULL);

  printf("%Lf in hex: 0x", src);
  for (size_t i = 0ul; i < sizeof src; ++i)
    printf("%X", dest[i]);
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/59KfKc9dr)